# Assign Incremental User ID Numbers in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We have a vuejs project with a google firestore DB and we need to assign all of our users a unique File number. It has to be numeric, 6 digits, and start at 000052.

We have approximately 4500 users.

I would like to use google cloud functions. How can I assign this File number to every user that is incrementally greater for every user?

I'm toying with trying to use firestore's limit query to find the previous user then increment the File # in the current user, etc., but that seems clunky.

```
db.collection('users').orderBy(id).get()
.then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    let last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
    let next = db.collection('users')
    .startAfter(last.data().id)
    .limit(1)
    db.collection('users').doc(next.id).set({
      fileId: last.id++
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Is there some problem, or does something you've written not work the way you expect?

Comment: Hey Doug... honestly I'm not sure the best way to proceed. I've tried simply removing the non-numbers from the firebase user uid, but there isn't always enough characters and no guarantee that the result will be unique

Comment: I'm toying with trying to use firestore's limit query to find the previous user then increment the File # in the next user, but that seems clunky.

Answer (score 1):

A few options I can think of:

- Your current approach *could* work, as long as you:

  - Order by *descending* ID, to make sure you get the last/highest ID.
  - Use a transaction to update the database, and security rules to reject a user overwriting an already existing ID.
- It's probably simpler to guarantee the uniqueness if you have a collection where you use these IDs as the document keys, since IDs are by definition unique in their collection. This can either be your current/main collection, or a secondary collection that just tracks the claimed IDs. Here too, a transaction + security rules are the key to ensuring uniqueness.
- Alternatively you can just generate a random ID in your scheme, and then perform the same transaction+rules logic as in the previous approach.
- You could also create a document that keeps the highest ID that you've given out, and then read-increment-write that document for each new user. Again, this will need to be done in a transaction. This is quite close to how many database systems increment their auto-increment values.

Comment: IDs are by definition unique in their collection or across the entire project? Are there any possibilities to have duplicate IDs in two different collections that exist in the same Firebase project?

Comment: Yes. But note that the auto-generated IDs from Firestore are statistically guaranteed to be unique.